# React + Backbone, Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

**Note:** This is a react error being thrown.

So I am trying an experiment where I render a post component from a backbone router based on that page. Now I know you would not typically do things this way, things can get messy and such. But again **It's just an experiment**.

So I have the following route in backbone (Note the react call):

```
AisisWriter.Routers.Posts = Backbone.Router.extend({

  writer_posts: null,

  posts: null,

  mountNode: $('#blog-manage'),

  routes : {
      '': 'index'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.writer_posts = new AisisWriter.Collections.Posts();
  },

  index: function() {
    var options = { reset: true };
    this.writer_posts.fetch(options).then(this.postsRecieved, this.serverError);
  },

  // Deal with the posts received
  postsRecieved: function(collection, response, options) {
    this.posts = collection;

    // Walk through the posts.
    $.each(this.posts, function(key, value){
      // value is an array of objects.
      $.each(value, function(index, post_object){
        React.renderComponent(new Post({post: post_object}), this.mountNode);
      });
    });
  },

  // Deal with any server errors
  serverError: function() {
    console.log('There was an error trying to fetch the posts.');
  }

});
```

The idea is that it should spit out a post title on to the page, one right after the other (I have a feeling it will only do it once).

But the issue is that the console is saying:

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Is this because of how I am trying to render the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`React.renderComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent) renders a component into a real DOM element. The exception is being thrown because you aren't passing a DOM element as the required second argument.

> ```
> ReactComponent renderComponent(
>   ReactComponent component,
>   DOMElement container,
>   [function callback]
> )
> ```
>
> Render a React component into the DOM in the supplied
>   container and return a reference to the component.

If you just want the HTML from React, you can use [`React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponenttostaticmarkup) instead.

Comment: So I updated the code in my post to give it a node - which does exist, but I am not sure if I doing it right as the error is the same ...

Comment: `this` is not what you expect inside the loops. You need to set the context of the `$.each` call: `$.each(function() { ... }, this);`.

Answer (score 10):

You're setting `this.mountNode` to `$('#blog-manage')`, which is a jQuery object (essentially an array of nodes). If you instead do

```
mountNode: $('#blog-manage')[0]
```

or

```
mountNode: $('#blog-manage').get(0)
```

then you'll have reference to the actual DOM node.

Comment: this is what the Backbone source does. It looks jenky/hacky but I guess that's how it works.