# React 13.3 unmountComponentAtNode() Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-testutils

I'm getting the following error in my testing suite when I upgrade from React 12.2 to React 13.3:

> Error: Invariant Violation: unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target
>   container is not a DOM element.

I'm using [this blog post](http://maketea.co.uk/2014/05/22/building-robust-web-apps-with-react-part-3.html#react-test-utilities) to test my code using Jasmine. The error occurs in this code:

```
describe("A component", function() {

  var instance;
  var container = document.createElement("div");

  afterEach(function() {
    if (instance && instance.isMounted()) {
      // Only components with a parent will be unmounted
      React.unmountComponentAtNode(instance.getDOMNode().parent);
    }
  });
  ...rest of test suite...
  // the instances of renderIntoDocument that cause the failure look like the below
  it("Causes my test suite to fail.", function() {
    instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyReactElement/>);
  });
)};
```

I know that `getDOMNode()` is deprecated but that's not what's causing the error.

When I inspect the `instance.getDOMNode()` it returns the given instance, but when it errors out, the `instance.getDOMNode().parent` is undefined. Calling `React.unmountComponentAtNode` on this undefined variable is causing the error.

Answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416407/2532070) suggest that there's some kind of race condition going on but I'm not sure how that would apply to my testing suite. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix is to change:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(instance.getDOMNode().parent);
```

to:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(instance.getDOMNode().parentNode);
```

Or, if you're moving from `getDOMNode()` to `findDOMNode()`:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(React.findDOMNode(instance).parentNode);
```