# Meteor React Tutorial Step 2 did not work

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I am doing the Meteor React simple-todos tutorial.
First step was just to create the app, cd into the app directory and run meteor. So far so good.

I made the changes as given in Step 2, but the to do list does not display. I get a blank screen.

Code is exactly the same as give on https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components
No error messages are displayed either in browser or console.

Versions: Meteor 1.5.2.1, OS = Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: You are required to post your problem code here: [mcve]

Comment: if the tuto did not work, tell them. Without code and errors's messages we can't help you

Comment: Code is exactly same as given in the tutorial at https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

No error messages displayed.

Comment: Your link to the tutorial is of no value to anyone should that link change or go dead. That is why your question has been downvoted and will eventually be deleted.

Comment: So why wasn't question 36137862 downgraded and "eventually" deleted? #justasking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. The solution is to change Task.jsx as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Task extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <li>{this.props.task.text}</li>
      );
  }
}

Task.propTypes = {
    task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

This is given on the github page meteor/simple-todos-react. Link is
https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/commit/ef2c0f0e13af648e784f0c96fe573d923009f919

Answer (score 9):

Try removing `Blaze`

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
```

And add `static-html`

```
meteor add static-html
```

Before that, make sure you have no typos in your files. You can copy the code from these files. Don't worry these codes are just for the step 2.

[client/main.html](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/b8c5da655108be87962f794f2814e2036a12a7e4/client/main.html)

[client/main.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/4459f38b759d17ade45da61e67265fb48e6f39c5/client/main.js)

[imports/ui/App.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/3f57957fe2f5797f651f2892374a99e626d97d72/imports/ui/App.js)

[imports/ui/Task.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/3084ff5657bb50fb6c14772b0af820f6760933d8/imports/ui/Task.js)

If this does not work you can always revert back using the commands `add` instead of `remove` to add back `blaze` and remove `static-html`.

Answer (score 1):

Spent hours on this tonight. Here's what I eventually did that fixed it

1. I removed blaze `meteor remove blaze-html-templates`
2. Add static html `meteor add static-html`. Not doing this results in `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`
3. Change `Task.jsx` so that it becomes and in `App.js` change the import statement to `import Task from './Task.jsx';`

Content of `Task.jsx`

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Task extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <li>{this.props.task.text}</li>
   );
 }
}

Task.propTypes = {
    task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

See other discussion [here](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/issues/71)