# React project getting "Target container is not a DOM element" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a react project for school and am getting the following error when trying to load the web server:

```
Error: Target container is not a DOM element. react-dom.development.js:26091
    render React
    js index.js:7
    js main.chunk.js:566
    Webpack 7
        __webpack_require__
        fn
        1
        __webpack_require__
        checkDeferredModules
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
```

The index.js code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

How can I solve this so I can start playing around with the look of the webpage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Error: Target Container is not a DOM Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416334/react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check your `public/index.html` file and make sure you've got this in there.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Did you use

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
```

to get started? It will generate this file with the root div for you automatically

Comment: I've got it working, it was to do with what you were talking about. Thank you.

Comment: awesome! Feel free to accept this answer if it was helpful to you :)