# after installing react showing Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I installed react then acc to a tutorial video I deleted all files in `src` directory and then created new `index.js`, `index.css` and `app.js` and other files but now it is showing an error for me

I also googled it; some answers were corrected but rearranging script position and some were corrected by giving id root in `app.js` to a `<div>` but all those are not working for me.

This is the error:
`Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just installed ReactJS and now it is showing the above error. Can someone please, help me to solve the problem?

PS: For further reference following is a screenshot of the error I get.
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Where is your `index.html`? Do you have an element with the ID of `root`?

Comment: did you also delete index.html file or did you change id which was given inside index.html ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Error: Target Container is not a DOM Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416334/react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros no it doesn't solve my question

Comment: If Crispen's answer worked for you, then the linked question has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53665248/6126373) that solves your question and it's a duplicate. No worries though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `index.html` file with an element which has an id `root`, and make sure your index.html file is in the public directory

Comment: please vote for the answer, it can help someone in the future