# I want to create a react Portal component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We are using react.
I want to create a Portal component and enclose a Drawer component in the Portal component.
I have created a Poratl component, but the following error occurs.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

errorMesssage

> _react.default.createPortal is not a function

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-microservice-lcgd2?file=/src/Drawer.tsx:0-904)

```
import ReactDOM from "react";
import createPortal from "react-dom";

export const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("portal");
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
};
```

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Portal } from "./Portal";

type Props = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClose: () => void;
};

export const Drawer = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Portal>
      <Overlay isOpen={props.isOpen} onClick={props.onClose} />
      <DrawerModal {...props}>{props.children}</DrawerModal>
    </Portal>
  );
};

const DrawerModal = styled.div<Props>`
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: ${({ isOpen }: Props) => (isOpen ? 400 : 0)}px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.24, 1);
`;

const Overlay = styled.div<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: ${(props: { isOpen: boolean }) => (props.isOpen ? 0 : -1)};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` instead of `import ReactDOM from 'react';`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; // Update this line

export const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("portal");
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
};
```

Comment: Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

Comment: I rewrote it but got another error message.

Comment: Error
Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: @yyyrrr Your code is missing an element with id "portal". Next time, if you come up with an error, try to copy and paste it to the Google search bar. I found a stackoverflow's question that is similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416334/react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element

Comment: I saw it, but I didn't understand it.

Comment: This line `import createPortal from "react-dom";` is now incorrect with this change since it actually has the same value as the first import.

Comment: @AlexWayne good point. I updated the answer.