# Error: Target container is not a DOM element with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made this React app but i keep getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Can someone help me please? This is my index.html and index.js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I've already tried every possible solutions that are uploaded to the internet, but unfortunately non of them hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 20):

As the [docs say](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#createroot), the signature is:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootNode).render(<App />);
```

And it replaces:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootNode)
```

So you need to change your code to

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root"),
)
.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Comment: And I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Double check that what you're passing into `createRoot` is actually a DOM element.

Comment: It is. Even supplied it an empty div and it still throws the error.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error, and this page helped me fix it:
https://www.sharooq.com/solved-createroot-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element

Probably your call to document.getElementById("root") is happening before the page has finished setting up the DOM. Try moving your code into:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    ReactDOM.createRoot(...)
});
```

Comment: The listener doesn't even trigger

Comment: This helped in my case but I would prefer to load the script tag with defer instead

Comment: See my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

from the react documentation, https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#createroot

```
Replace this line of your code

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

line of your code with this code

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This should fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem for an extremely silly reason. I accidentally swapped `index.js` around so it ran before my `div id="root"` was created. So the DOM truly didn't exist at the moment react was looking for it.

Illustrative examples:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    // WRONG! React tries to access the DOM before it is loaded.
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    // RIGHT! React will access the DOM after it is loaded.
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was, that the dom traversal was triggered too early, such that it could not find that element correctly.

Loading the script with `defer` fixed it for me:

```js
= javascript_pack_tag 'index', defer: true
```

You can learn more on why this also generally a good idea [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/504104-you-should-probably-load-your-javascript-with-script-defer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I included the `<script>` tag in the `index.html` file as well. I managed to resolve my issue using the solution [in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416407/4526888) I also ran into this issue when serving my app via Webpack 5's [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) so I'd be curious to know what your serving your application with and/or the configuration to see if this perhaps isn't an issue in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest React version, you can render your component as follows:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root'));

root.render (
 <React.StrictMode>
    <App/ >
 <React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: Other anwsers already provided this code, duplicating is unnecessary.